# Injection doesn't work in Arquillian test

Tags: java, integration-testing, jboss-arquillian

i'm trying to do simple app using JavaEE and currently i'm stuck with arquillian test. I have a BookRepository class like this:

```
package com.pluralsight.bookstore.repository;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import static javax.transaction.Transactional.TxType.SUPPORTS;

@Transactional(SUPPORTS)
public class BookRepository {

}
```

And test class BookRepositoryTest :

```
package com.pluralsight.bookstore.repository;

@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class BookRepositoryTest {

    @Inject
    private BookRepository bookRepository;

    @Deployment
    public static JavaArchive createDeployment() {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class)
                .addClass(BookRepository.class)
                .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml")
                .addAsManifestResource("META-INF/test-persistence.xml", "persistence.xml");
    }

    @Test
    public void create() {
        assertNotNull(bookRepository);
    }
}
```

Running the test results in :

```
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 9.864 sec <<< FAILURE!
    create(com.pluralsight.bookstore.repository.BookRepositoryTest)  Time elapsed: 0.287 sec  <<< ERROR!
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.pluralsight.bookstore.repository.BookRepositoryTest.create(BookRepositoryTest.java:38)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            ...
```

Without any explanation. As I checked with assertNotNull, bookRepository is always null so the injection doesn't work here i guess. The project structure looks like this:
[image]

I tried looking for answer for some time now and i'm still at the same place. For the container i run test with wildfly remote, and have WildFly running in the background.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Is the bookRepository propery/variable being set or is it null?

Comment: @JeffreyPhillipsFreeman well i thought it's being initialized with the injection. I'm following a course on pluralsight with this and there it was all it took to pass. But the course is not new and maybe something changed since then. So should it be initialized somewhere in the test? Code I pasted is tbh the only code i have right now besides book model and language enum.

Comment: @Animu The inject annotation probably initialized it for you assuming you didnt make a mistake in your configuration somewhere. Why dont you manually check that its value isnt null to be sure and that way we can rule that out as a possibility.

Comment: Ahh in that case it seems that *IS* your problem. The issue is that the inject isnt working and bookRepository is null. So that really narrows down how to solve this.

Comment: @MaxVollmer changed to minimal code. Thanks again for notice :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay so i finally made it work. Apparently i was using the wrong '@Inject' annotation. I was using arquillian one, and not javax one. I changed

```
import org.jboss.arquillian.core.api.annotation.Inject;
```

in my test case class to

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
```

And it worked like a charm. Was really annoying to track down and actually i found it by dumb luck so i hope this will help someone in the future.

Comment: I am following the same tutorial and got stuck in the exact same place. You are a lifesaver. If anyone else is following this tutorial, the author uses a lot of intellij generation so connecting the dots is kinda hard if you're new to it.

Answer (score 0):

Wildfly is a Java EE 7 compliant AS, in JavaEE 7 CDI beans by default are discovered if annotated, have look at [Default CDI Enablement in Java EE 7](https://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/default-cdi-enablement-in-java-ee-7), which maybe your case you have an empty beans.xml.
So to have the `BookRepository` injected you have to add a scope annotation (see [CDI scopes](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/scopescontexts.html)), for istance `@ApplicationScoped`:

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Transactional(SUPPORTS)
public class BookRepository {

}
```

Or you have to include a beans.xml, with discovery mode `all`, as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
       http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

put it under src/test/resources to include it in your test modify as follow:

```
package com.pluralsight.bookstore.repository; 

@RunWith(Arquillian.class) 
public class BookRepositoryTest { 

    @Inject 
    private BookRepository bookRepository; 

    @Deployment 
    public static JavaArchive createDeployment() { 
         return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class) 
                                         .addClass(BookRepository.class) 
                                         .addAsManifestResource("META-INF/beans.xml", "beans.xml")
                                         .addAsManifestResource("META-INF/test-persistence.xml", "persistence.xml"); 
     } 

    //...

}
```

Comment: I tried to add @ApplicationScoped to the class but it tells me "'@ApplicationScoped' not applicable to type". Also tried to add beans.xml at the bookstore-back\src\main\resources\META-INF\beans.xml, but it highlights "beans" as not resolvable.

Comment: I edited the answer for beans.xml. Is @ApplicationScoped [this](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/1.0/javax/enterprise/context/ApplicationScoped.html)?

Comment: I added the beans.xml you posted in test/resources/META-INF/beans.xml and it still didn't work. And about the "@ApplicationScoped", i don't know if I understand you correctly but i have "import org.jboss.arquillian.core.api.annotation.ApplicationScoped;". Tried to import the one you posted but cannot resolve after javax.enterprise